# Me da este error cant set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola gente estoy utilizando passport-local y lo que quiero hacer es que se muestre el usuario cuando hace el login

Mi codigo es este

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User=require("../model/usuario"); 
   
 

 var local = function (app) {

passport.use(new localStrategy({
   usernameField: 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   
  },
  function (username, password,done) {
    User.findOne({username: username})
   .then(function (user) {
    if (!user) return done(null, false, {message: `El username ${username} no existe!`});
    if (user.password === password) {
     
     
     return done(null, user);


    } else {
     return done(null, false, {message: 'El password es incorrecto'});
    }
   });
  
  }
 ));

 app.post('/regis', passport.authenticate('local', {



    successRedirect: '/extra',
    failureRedirect: '/regis/',
    failureFlash: true,
    
    
 }));


};

module.exports = local;
```

.....

```js
var usuario=require("../model/user");
var useri=require("../model/usuario");


function usuariosguardados(app,io){

app.route("/salir")
.get((req,res)=>{
req.logout();
            res.redirect('/');
})


app.route("/extra")
.get((req,res)=>{

 useri.findOne({username:req.user.username},(err,user)=>{
if(user){
 res.render("extra",{user:user})
}
})




usuario.findOne({id_social:req.user.id},(err,user)=>{
if(user){
 res.redirect("/")
}else{
res.render("extra");
}

})


})

.post(function(req,res){
 if(req.user.provider=="facebook"){
var user=new usuario({
id_social:req.user.id,
userred:req.user._json.name,
username:req.body.username,
email:req.body.email,
foto:"http://graph.facebook.com/" + req.user.id + "/picture"

})

user.save(function(err){
if(err){
 console.log(err);
return
}})

}

  res.redirect('/');

})


app.route("/registroo")

.get((req,res)=>{
res.render("registroo")

})

.post(function(req,res){

 
 var usera = new useri({
   username: req.body.username,
   password: req.body.password
  });
  usera.save(function (err) {
   if (!err) {
return res.redirect('/regis');
}else{
 console.log(err);
}
  })

})
app.route("/regis")
.get(function(req,res){
 let error_message = req.flash('error')[0];
  res.locals.error_message = error_message;
res.render("regis")
})



}

module.exports=usuariosguardados
```

Lo que quiero hacer yo que se  muestre el usuario  eso funciona pero al hacer eso me sale el error ese y el css no funciona ni el js

esto es lo que me aparece

[image: VEZ NO ME APARECE EL CSSS Y ME DA EL ERROR]

Comment: El mensaje de los headers, en alguna parte de tu código estás mandando un response y en otra línea vuelves a mandarlo. En el log de errores identifica en que línea de x archivo está sucediendo eso y solo manda un response. Si el css y js no funciona es porque no has definido la ruta que contendrá tus assets, estás ocupando express?

Answer (score 0):

,Antes que nada, ***require()*** no es parte del estándar de **Javascript**, se construye en ***Node.JS*** para cargar los módulos, que sería algo similar como añadir etiquetas ***script***  en tu código HTML.

Si te dice que no está definido algo me dice que no tienes configurado bien la estructura de tu proyecto en ***Node.JS*** o tienes error de typo en algún módulo importado.

Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo la respuesta a esta [pregunta - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) , que te ayudará mucho más al entender como tomar las decisiones correctas en el control de tus scripts con ***Node.JS***

¡Un saludo!